# Chrome/Firefox won't play HLS video/mp2t video stream in HTML player

Tags: javascript, encoding, video-streaming, html5-video, hls.js

I’m currently working on a web application whose main purpose is streaming/timeshifting TV channels. Application is written in Javascript React framework and for web player we are using [CookPete ReactPlayer](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) with integrated hls.js. We have managed to successfully play live TV channels but unfortunately, we are experiencing some issues with timeshifting channels

Live streams are distributed over [XtreamUI](https://xtream-ui.com/) server as a m3u8 lists, and have this kind of format 
example.org/live/username/password/channel_1.m3u8
So when a user is watching Live TV this kind of URL goes to the player source and CookPete player + hls.js are doing their magic with parsing/processing m3u8 list which results in playing video flawlessly.

Here comes the problem, for timeshift XtreamUI are using this kind of URL [example.org/streaming/timeshift.php?username=XXX&password=XXX&stream=2&start=2020-04-26:19-23&duration=7](https://example.org/streaming/timeshift.php?username=XXX&password=XXX&stream=2&start=2020-04-26:19-23&duration=7)
As you can see its PHP script which STREAMS raw bytes into the player.  Here are response headers from /streaming/timeshift.php

[image: Web inspector]

As you can notice, the Content-type is video/mp2t which for some reason cannot be played in the browser environment.( Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, IE 11). This warning pops up.

[image: Console warning]

On the other hand, Safari browser on Mac video is playing completely normal, but the request from Safari is a little bit different. This is a screenshot from Safari's console network tab. As you can see there are several requests with different byte-ranges.

[image: Network tab]

We are seeking a solution which will provide playing timeshift video (video/mp2t content) in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and IE 11. All suggestions/advices are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> the Content-type is video/mp2t which for some reason cannot be played in the browser environment

This is because chrome and Firefox do not support mpeg transport streams, and safari does. hls.js works because it knows how to read a binary ts file, and rewrite it as mp4 fragment before sending to the the media source extensions buffer. You will need to do the same. Take a look at mux.js.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer @szatmary. I am in same shoes and using plyr-react with signed Cloudfront URLs for my HLS media in S3

Answer (score -1):

In Firefox install a codec by running this command.

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec58
```

Install a similar codec in chrome too. It should fix the problem.